# How to rewrite code from Lisp to Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

It is impossible to rewrite the code from Lisp language to Scheme language, an error occurs, help to correct.
For example `(cadr x)` is equivalent to `(car (cdr x))`
a function `(cadr x)` is equivalent to `(car (cdr x))`, and I don't know how to interpret the `numberp` function.
Lisp code:

```
(defun deriv (f x)
  (cond ((numberp f) 0)
        ((eq f x) 1)
        ((eq (car f) '+) `(+ ,(deriv (cadr f) x) ,(deriv (caddr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) '-) `(- ,(deriv (cadr f) x) ,(deriv (caddr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) '*) `(+ (* ,(caddr f) ,(deriv (cadr f) x)) (* ,(cadr f) ,(deriv (caddr f) x))))
        ((eq (car f) '^) `(* (* ,(caddr f) (^ ,(cadr f) (- ,(caddr f) 1))) ,(deriv (cadr f) x)))))
```

How I tried to write this code on Scheme:

```
(define deriv (f x)
  (cond
        ((eq? f x) 1)
        ((eq? (car f) '+) '(+ ,(deriv (car (cdr f) x)) ,(deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x)))))
        ((eq? (car f) '-) '(- ,(deriv (car (cdr f) x)) ,(deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x)))))
        ((eq? (car f) '*) '(+ (* ,(car (cdr (cdr f))) ,(deriv (car (cdr f) x))) (* ,(car (cdr f)) ,(deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x))))))
        ((eq? (car f) '^) '(* (* ,(car (cdr (cdr f))) (^ ,(car (cdr f)) (- ,(car (cdr (cdr f))) 1))) ,(deriv (car (cdr f)) x)))))
```

an error occurs

```
define: bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier) in: (define deriv (f x) (cond ((eq? f x) 1) ((eq? (car f) (quote +)) (quote (+ (unquote (deriv (car (cdr f) x))) (unquote (deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x))))))) ((eq? (car f) (quote -)) (quote (- (unquote (deriv (car (cdr f) x))) (unquote (deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x))))))) ((eq? (car f) (quote *)) (quote (+ (* (unquote (car (cdr (cdr f)))) (unquote (deriv (car (cdr f) x)))) (* (unquote (car (cdr f))) (unquote (deriv (car (cdr (cdr f) x)))))))) ((eq? (car f) (quote ^)) (quote (* (* (unquote (car (cdr (cdr f)))) (^ (unquote (car (cdr f))) (- (unquote (car (cdr (cdr f)))) 1))) (unquote (deriv (car (cdr f)) x)))))))
```

p.s. Sorry for my English

Comment: what language (`#lang`) are you using?

Comment: use #lang racket

Comment: `#lang racket` has `cadr`, has it not?

Comment: Used, but I can't use them. These are the conditions of the job. Thanks :)

Comment: ah, OK, but it seems you do know how to deal with this: just use the chained applications of car and cdr according to the letters a and d: e.g., caddar -> (car (cdr (cdr (car .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `number?` instead of `numberp`, and write

```
(define (func arg1 arg2 ...) ...)
```

in place of `(defun func (arg arg2 ...) ...)`.

Also, don't be replacing the backquote `` ` `` with a simple quote `'`. Keep it.